# I want to create drill down report. But what is the format of hyper link to give parameter for that drill down reports

Tags: crystal-reports

After clicking on hyperlink of main report to reaching at drill down report. I'm getting error like (BALANCE_JOBCARD_DETAIL.rpt Index was outside the bounds of the array.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is _not_ a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first by doing some research on the subject and making an attempt to write the code. If you have issues with that code, then feel free to ask a question requesting debugging help. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Their is a array written in a formula which is returning the error, first set the formula in BALANCE_JOBCARD_DETAIL.rpt  report